# How to check if an object has been created yet?

Tags: java, instantiation

**The Problem**

I have an Army class that is run twice (by a separate driver class) to create two armies. In that Army class there are the following statements to create new objects from the other class files I have:

```
  public final Archer archer = new Archer(this);
  public final Catapult catapult = new Catapult(this);
  public final NCatapult ncatapult = new NCatapult(this); //Ninja catapult
  public final Ninja ninja = new Ninja(this);
  public final Horse horse = new Horse(this);
  public final Samurai samurai = new Samurai(this);
```

The constructors for each of those objects require an "Army" object in their constructor method arguments, hence the `this` keyword used in the instantiations.

So. Within a method in the Horse class, I create a new "Warrior" object, because a Warrior wasn't instantiated initially in the Army class.

```
private boolean warriorCreated = false;
  public void dismount(){
    if (!warriorCreated){
      Warrior warrior = new Warrior(myArmy);
      warriorCreated = true;
      myArmy.getOurArmyWindow().getTabbedPane().addTab("(Ethan)", new ImageIcon("images/warriorIcon.jpg"), warrior.genGetPanel()); //This is just adding the Warrior's tab to my GUI. It's not relevant to the problem.
    }
    ...//Some stuff to handle when the method is called and warriorCreated is true
    }//end dismount()
```

You will notice how it uses the variable "myArmy" in the constructor for the Warrior. That is simply the Army object that was passed when the Horse was instantiated.

```
public Horse(Army armyInstance){ //A constructor that takes in whatever Army object called it
    myArmy = armyInstance;
  }
```

Within all of the different instantiated objects, I can access the other opposing Army with the use of a `myArmy.getEnemyArmyInstance()` method. I don't want to explain in detail how it works and take up even more space than I already am, so just trust me that it works.

This means that usually I can reference an object instantiated by the opposing Army by calling something like `Ninja enemyNinja = myArmy.getEnemyArmyInstance().ninja;` (I can replace "Ninja" with whatever other object I want to reference).

However, because the Warrior object is instantiated by a Horse class method and not right from the get-go in each Army object, I first want to check if it has been instantiated yet before trying to reference it from a separate object.

This is where I run into trouble. Any time I try to check if a Warrior object has been instantiated yet, it gives me an error at compile-time.

For example, consider this check:

```
public void checkForWarrior(){
if (myArmy.getEnemyArmyInstance().warrior != null){
  System.out.println("A warrior exists!");
}
else
  System.out.println("There is no warrior!");
}
```

It throws the error

```
error: cannot find symbol   
if (myArmy.getEnemyArmyInstance().warrior != null){
                                 ^
symbol:   variable warrior
location: class Army
```

**What I Have Tried**

I thought maybe the Warrior object created wasn't a member (that is the correct term, right?) of Army, so I tried adding ".horse" to the line only to get a similar result.

```
   if (myArmy.getEnemyArmyInstance().horse.warrior != null){
                                          ^
   symbol:   variable warrior
   location: variable horse of type Horse
```

I even tried adding a boolean that would get turned on in the Horse class when a Warrior is instantiated, and then checking for that first. But no dice.

```
private boolean mounted = true; //This is in the Horse class and is set to
false when a Warrior is instantiated.
```

In the other classes:

```
if (myArmy.getEnemyArmyInstance().horse.getMounted()){
Warrior enemy = myArmy.getEnemyArmyInstance().warrior;//Still gives me an
//error that it cannot find the variable warrior. (I tried adding .horse to
//this, too).
```

**The Question**

From objects that aren't the Horse that instantiated it, how do I check to see if a Warrior object has been instantiated yet so that I can reference it from those other objects?

Comment: If you would like me to clarify something or add more information, please ask me to first before immediately down-voting. I tried to make this as comprehensive as possible so people would not be confused or angry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you need to add the following to your `Army` class:

```
public Warrior warrior;
```

Then in your `Horse` class:

```
  public void dismount(){
    if (myArmy.warrior == null){
      myArmy.warrior = new Warrior(myArmy);
      myArmy.getOurArmyWindow().getTabbedPane().addTab("(Ethan)", new ImageIcon("images/warriorIcon.jpg"), warrior.genGetPanel()); //This is just adding the Warrior's tab to my GUI. It's not relevant to the problem.
    }
    ...//Some stuff to handle when the method is called and warriorCreated is true
    }//end dismount()
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, I see. This is a viable work-around to my problem. Does this mean there is no way to reference the Warrior object from other classes if it is /completely/ instantiated (AKA without giving it a variable name in the Army class) in the Horse class?